# After applying style on dropdown, OnSelectedIndexChanged not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have applied script on dropdownlist for stylish look and style is applied properly
,but in .cs page(code page) OnSelectedIndexChanged of dropdownlist is not working properly.

**My html code is :**

```
<link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="default"/>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.styledselect_form_1').selectbox({ inputClass: "styledselect_form_1" });
         });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddprice" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddprice_SelectedIndexChanged" class="styledselect_form_1">
<asp:ListItem Value="0">BY PRICE</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Low to High</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">High to Low</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</body>
```

**My source code is:**

```
protected void ddprice_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
}
```

**And my script in css class name screen.css is**

```
/*  STYLED Dropdown*/   
div.selectbox-wrapper2  {
background-color: #e3e3e3;
border: none;
border-bottom: none;
margin: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
max-height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
padding: 0px;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
width: 400px;
}
div.selectbox-wrapper2 ul   {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
div.selectbox-wrapper2 ul li.selected2  {
background-color: #94b52c;
color: #fff;
}
div.selectbox-wrapper2 ul li.current2   {
background-color: #94b52c;
color: #fff;
}
div.selectbox-wrapper2 ul li    {
border-bottom: none;
color: #393939;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 12px;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 6px 2px 6px 10px;
}
.styledselect_form_1    {
background: url(../images/price-2.jpg) left no-repeat;
border: none;
border-left: none;
color: #393939;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
height: 24px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 7px 0 0 6px;
text-align: left;
width: 192px;
}
```

Comment: Run IE browser ,then tell me for if you got any error .

Comment: @RameshRams: I had tried in IE but Still not working.

Comment: You got any error when runtime ?

Comment: No, Actually on select of dropdown it is not firing an event OnselectChange which is on .cs page

Comment: You miised the form tag . The dropdown control should be used in inside of form tag

Comment: @RameshRams: Actually in question i had made mistake of not putting form tag. but in actual i had putten the form tag

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="default"/>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

             $(function () {
       $("[id*=ddprice]").selectbox({ inputClass: "styledselect_form_1" });
         });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddprice" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddprice_SelectedIndexChanged" class="styledselect_form_1">
<asp:ListItem Value="0">BY PRICE</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Low to High</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">High to Low</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</body>
```

Comment: Its still not working. I think so this script is making overlay on dropdown so its is not firing the "onselectindexchange" event, can u make help of make me find out some other good css for making my dropdown look stylish?

Comment: may it helps - stackoverflow.com/questions/9289492/asp-net-dropdownlist-selected-index-changed-and-textchanged-events-not-fire-c

Comment: that one was not helpful to me.

Comment: Black Cloud: Can you give me your personal email so that i can forward you my project, so that u can make me found my problem easily.

Comment: ya sure .. give me your mail address .

Comment: mitesh.24jain@gmail.com
and also give me your ID, i will send you my demo project.

Comment: I have send you my trial project on your mail. Please have a check.Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You have already assigned styledselect_form_1 in dropdown. so why you add the  styledselect_form_1 class  one more time in ddl  threw jquery ?remove this below line ,then check

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.styledselect_form_1').selectbox({ inputClass: "styledselect_form_1" });
         });
</script>
```

**Update**

You miised the form tag . The dropdown  control should be used in inside of form tag

Comment: I had removed the below line, but the style applied to the dropdown is not seen any more

Comment: In actual i had made my dropdown inside the form tag but here i forget to display

Comment: Can you give me your personal email so that i can forward you my project, so that u can make me found my problem easily.